# Negating the definition of continuity

Tags: analysis, continuity

A map $f$ is continuous in $x_0\in X$ if \begin{align*}\forall\epsilon>0~\exists\delta>0~\forall x\in X: |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon.\end{align*}
Negating this yields \begin{align}\exists\epsilon>0~\forall\delta>0~\exists x\in X: |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|\geq\epsilon. ~(1)\end{align}
But what is the mistake when saying that \begin{align}\exists\epsilon>0~\forall\delta>0~\exists x\in X: |x-x_0|<\delta \wedge |f(x)-f(x_0)|\geq\epsilon~(2)\end{align} is the negation? Is $(2)$ a consequence of $(1)$? Can anybody give me an example of a map with a discontinuous point where $(2)$ is true but $(1)$ is not?

Comment: Permit me to nitpick: In English, the noun form of 'continuous' is *continuity*. I would also add that using more words and less symbols helps people to understand math. I prefer 'there exists' to '$\exists$'

Comment: To expand on the below answer, a concrete situation where $(1)$ fails is when a function is vacuously continuous. For example, a real function with a singleton domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your statement $(1)$ is *not* the negation of the original statement.

Negating the original statement yields

$$\exists \epsilon > 0 \forall \delta>0 \exists x\in X: \neg\left(|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon\right)$$

Remember, you have to negate the *internal* statement as well - the negation of $\forall x: P(x)$ is $\exists x: \neg P(x)$.

Now, also remember that the negation of $$A\implies B$$ is **NOT** $$A\implies \neg B,$$ but rather $$A\land \neg B.$$

This is because $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $\neg A\lor B$ which, when negated (deMorgans law), becomes $\neg\neg A\land \neg B$, which is equivalent to $A\land \neg B$.

Comment: The last sentence sort of trails off